# Message flow problems with NSTableHeaderView and NSTableHeaderCell while trying to produce transparent NSTableView Header

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableheaderview, nstableheadercell

**Problem:** I am trying to create a custom transparent `TableView` Header and I have created subclasses of `NSTableHeaderView` and `NSTableHeaderCell` and overridden `-drawWithFrame:inView` and `-drawInteriorWithFrame:inView` in the `NSTableHeaderCell` subclass. These methods are working as expected, but only when the table column header is first drawn. After the user clicks on the table header, however, it is re-drawn with a white background. To get specific, here are the custom method implementations:

```
@interface MYTableHeaderCell : NSTableHeaderCell
@end

@implementation MYTableHeaderCell

-(void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView{
//[super drawWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];
NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:cellFrame];
NSColor *clearColor = [NSColor clearColor];
[clearColor setFill];
[path fill];
[self drawInteriorWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];
}

-(void)drawInteriorWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView{
//[super drawInteriorWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];
NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:cellFrame];
NSColor *clearColor = [NSColor clearColor];
[clearColor setFill];
[path fill];
NSRect titleRect = [self titleRectForBounds:cellFrame];
[self.attributedStringValue drawInRect:titleRect];
}

-(NSColor *)highlightColorWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView{
return [NSColor clearColor];
}

-(BOOL)isOpaque{
return NO;
}
```

When the table view header is first drawn, it 
[has a transparent background as intended.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEyDG.png)
After clicking on the header, however, it is 
[redrawn to have a white background.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4ESe.png)

As far as I can tell, after clicking on the table view header

```
-drawInteriorWithFrame:inView:
```

is still called when the header needs to be drawn. However,

```
-drawWithFrame:inView:
```

is not. It also appears that another class is drawing a white view underneath the cell text.

I have looked through the `NSTableHeaderCell` and `NSTableHeaderView` class descriptions along with all of their `superclasses` but I can't figure out why the white background is being drawn. I'm obviously missing something fundamental.

**Question:** What is causing the white view to be drawn?

Comment: Are you selecting or sorting the column? Switch `allowsColumnSelection` off or try overriding `highlight:withFrame:inView:`.

Answer (score 0):

The

```
highlight(flag: Bool, withFrame cellFrame: NSRect, inView controlView: NSView)
```

method is not implemented. Override this method and copy your code from your drawRect method in there and this should be done.